# Find Closest Matching Value in Data frame and Return Index

Tags: r, match

I have two data frames. The first is a set of variables where the last column is the sum of the values in each column by row. The second data frame is an index where the first column is a set of possible values that the rowSum values could fall in.

What I want to do is match the rowSum value from the first data frame with the closest value to it in the second data frame and return the value that goes along with that value in the second data frame, kind of like assigning a letter grade based on a test score.

```
a <- c(1.2, 2.3, 3.4)
b <- c(2.3, 3.4, 4.5)
c <- c(3.4, 4.5, 5.6)
score <- c(6.9, 10.2, 13.5)

Scores <- data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,score))

score <- c(15, 14, 13
       ,12, 11, 10
       ,9, 8, 7
       ,6, 5, 4
       ,3, 2, 1)

grade <-  c('A','A','A'
        ,'B','B','B'
        ,'C','C','C'
        ,'D','D','D'
        ,'F', 'F', 'F')

Grades <- data.frame(cbind(score,grade))


Scores$Grade <-
  Grades$grade[match(Scores$score, Grades$score)]
```

Expected:

```
a    b    c    score    Grade
1.2  2.3  3.4  6.9      C
2.3  3.4  4.5  10.2     B
3.4  4.5  5.6  13.5     A
```

Actual:

```
a    b    c    score    Grade
1.2  2.3  3.4  6.9      NA
2.3  3.4  4.5  10.2     NA
3.4  4.5  5.6  13.5     NA
```

I think this is because match() is not able to round decimals and so it cannot match to exact values. Is there a different function or method that can match values to the closest matching integer and return the corresponding Grade?

Comment: Try with `findInterval`. Please don't use `data.frame(cbind` as it mess up the data structures instead sshould be `data.frame(`

Comment: Try `rev(Grades$grade)[findInterval(Scores$score, rev(Grades$score))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with `findInterval`, but make sure that the dataset is created correctly, `cbind` returnss a `matrix` and a `matrix` can have only a single class.  Wrapping with `data.frame` propagate the same class to either `factor` or `character` depending on `stringsAsFactors = TRUE/FALSE` (if there is at least one `character` element).

Order the 'Grades' dataset by the 'score' column and apply `findInterval` to get the index of nearest matching value and use that for extracting the 'grade'

```
Scores <- data.frame(a,b,c,score)
Grades <- data.frame(score,grade)
Grades1 <- Grades[order(Grades$score),]
Scores$Grade <- Grades1$grade[findInterval(Scores$score, Grades1$score) +1]
```

---

or another option is a rolling join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Scores)[Grades, Grade := grade, on = .(score), roll = Inf]
Scores
#     a   b   c score Grade
#1: 1.2 2.3 3.4   6.9     C
#2: 2.3 3.4 4.5  10.2     B
#3: 3.4 4.5 5.6  13.5     A
```